# I want to join 4 tables in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Till know I join 3 table

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('dispatch_challan');
$this->db->join('challan_bilties', 'dispatch_challan.disp_id = challan_bilties.challan_id');
$this->db->join('bilty', 'challan_bilties.challan_bilties_id = bilty.id');
$this->db->where('dispatch_challan.disp_ch_no',$disp_ch_no); 

 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
```

My output is like this after join table
[image]

In above image the `Consignor` and `Consignee`  fetch id but i want name so i want to join 4th table i.e `ts_users`

In this table the full name of this `Consignor` and `Consignee`

```
                           ts_users table

               user_id  user_fullname  user_remark
                 1            abc         consignee
                 2            xyz         consignor
                 3            pqr         consignee
                 4            lmn         consignor
```

I want to get full name based on `Consignor` and `Consignee` from 4th table`(ts_users)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't really tell us where the `consignor` and `consignee` fields come from, you'll need to fill in the blanks (denoted as `xxx` below)

All you need is to join twice with the `ts_users` table. Add these:

```
$this->db->join('ts_users u1', 'xxx.consignor = u1.user_id');
$this->db->join('ts_users u2', 'xxx.consignee = u2.user_id');
```

Since you'll be joining twice with the same table, your resultset will be a bit confusing if you stick to `select *` so I'd recommend fetching only the fields you need. For instance:

```
$this->db->select('u1.user_id as consignor, u2.user_id as consignee, dispatch_challan.*, challan_bilties.*, bilty.*');
```

give it a shot and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

This is how to join any number of tables in codeigniter without any problems:

```
$this->db->select("
    $table_1.id AS table_1_id,
    $table_1.whatever AS table_1_whatever,
    $table_2.id AS table_2_id,
    $table_2.whatever AS table_2_whatever,
    $table_3.id AS table_3_id,
    $table_3.whatever AS table_3_whatever,
    $table_4.id AS table_4_id,
    $table_4.whatever AS table_4_whatever,
");
$this->db->join($table_2, "$table_2.id = $table_1.table_2_id", 'left');
$this->db->join($table_3, "$table_3.id = $table_1.table_3_id", 'left');
$this->db->join($table_4, "$table_4.id = $table_1.table_4_id", 'left');
```